# In Flask, how do you update an input field in a template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Being am new to Flask I read the manuals of Flask an Jinja and I know how to read a filed from a template, but not how to update the template.

My template has the following structure which I modified from the doco

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
      <dl>
        <dt>Documet:
        <dd><input   name=text size = 80 value = {{ AO_sDocument }} > </input >   
        <dd><input type=submit value=Analyse>
      </dl>
    </form>
```

and my Python has the following line

```
render_template('show_entries.html',   AO_sDocument=AO_sDocument )
```

Yest this line does not seem to update the field.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have some relevant portion of code missing in the snippet you posted. How is the variable AO_sDocument populated in python?

Comment: Is this example actually copied and pasted from your template? You do realise you're missing `"` around all your tag attributes (except action)? It wouldn't surprise me if AO_sDocument is valid, but the  browser's not able to parse your example successfully.

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Clements points out, your HTML has some markup errors. In order to guarantee all browsers can parse the HTML correctly, your template markup should look more like the following:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method="post" class="add-entry">
    <dl>
        <dt>Document:</dt>
        <dd><input name="text" size="80" value="{{ AO_sDocument }}" /></dd>
        <dd><input type="submit" value="Analyse" /></dd>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Alternately, you may wish to drop the use of `<dl>` and `<dt>` in favor of a `<label>`, which are ever so slightly more semantically correct:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method="post" class="add-entry">
    <label for="text">Document:</label>
    <input id="text" name="text" size="80" value="{{ AO_sDocument }}" />
    <input type="submit" value="Analyse" />
</form>
```